# ES 2015 Promise.all Doesn't Resolve

Tags: javascript, angular, ecmascript-6, nativescript

I am using nested `Promise.all` but the last `Promise.all` isn't resolving. Here is my code:

```
        let eventPromises = [];  
        for(let event of events) {
            event.customProperties = {};

            let localPromises = [];
            //map
            let locationPromise = this.getEventLocation(event.latitude, event.longitude)
            .then((address: LocationAddress) => {
                if(address) {
                    event.customProperties.address = address;
                }
                console.log('----------location promise-----------')
                return event;
            }); 
            localPromises.push(locationPromise); 
            //weather
             let weatherPromise = this.getWeather(event.latitude, event.longitude)
             .then(weatherInfo => {
                 event.customProperties.weather = weatherInfo;
            });
            localPromises.push(weatherPromise);

            let eventPromise = Promise.all(localPromises).then(() => {
                this.data.push(event);
                console.log('----------localPromises done-----------')
                return event;
            });                    
            eventPromises.push(eventPromise);
        }
        console.dir(eventPromises); //The __zone_symbol__state is always show null

        Promise.all(eventPromises).then(() => {
            console.log('----------------All events are done--------------------')
            //Its neveer called
        });
```

I want to execute code after `eventPromises` is resolved.

[image]

Comment: Is `eventPromises` iterable? If `__zone_symbol__state` is always null, how it can be resolved?

Comment: Perhaps describe what you're trying to achieve

Comment: @Deliaz yes the length of `eventPromises ` is 3

Comment: @jimmyweb I want to execute code after `eventPromises` is resolved.

Comment: @DotNetDreamer that I know ;) I want to know what specific goal are you trying to achieve.

Comment: @jimmyweb loop through objects, wait for weather api, location api and if data is prepared then push the final (complete) object. When all objects are prepared (with complete data), then execute final logic (broadcast event). The goal is to make the object complete with weather info and location info as it relies on 3rd party

Comment: Do you know that there's no error? Install an error handler (`.catch(…)`)!

Comment: I think you are doing too much things in one function "loop through objects, wait for weather api, location api and if data is prepared then push the final (complete) object. When all objects are prepared (with complete data), then execute final logic (broadcast event)." - keep it simple, create few functions with single responsibilities and this will easier to debugging

Comment: @Bergi those are in service and its working fine.

Comment: @Stwosch will try that